# A refinement of Faltings' lemma

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

In his proof of the Mordell conjecture, Faltings proved the following important result:

Let $K$ be a number field and $S$ a finite set of primes in $K$. Then for any $g \geq 2$ there exists a number $T(K,S,g)$ such that there are at most $T(K,S,g)$ many $K$-isogeny classes of abelian varieties $A$ of dimension $g$ defined over $K$ having good reduction outside of $S$.

Does the following uniform variant hold?

Let $S$ be a finite set of *rational primes*. For any positive integers $d, g \geq 2$ does there exist a number $T(S,d,g)$ such that for any number field $K$ with $[K : \mathbb{Q}] \leq d$, the number of $K$-isogeny classes of abelian varieties $A/K$ of dimension $g$ having good reduction outside the set $S_K$ of primes in $K$ above $S$ is bounded by $T(S,d,g)$?

One can even restrict the above question to only counting (isogeny classes of) abelian varieties with *potentially everywhere good reduction*.